# PowerShell Invoke-Expression command parameter contains comma

Tags: powershell, special-characters, mapped-drive

What should I do when a password contains PowerShell special characters?

```
Invoke-Expression -Command "net use x: $Path /USER:domain1\user1 7Ui4RT,@T /persistent:no"
```

This fails on syntax -- because PowerShell interprets `7Ui4RT,@T` as an array:

```
Invoke-Expression -Command "net use x: $Path /USER:domain1\user1 7Ui4RT`,@T /persistent:no"
```

This fails on syntax -- apparently because PowerShell can't interpret ``` 7Ui4RT``,@T ```

```
Invoke-Expression -Command "net use x: $Path /USER:domain1\user1 "7Ui4RT,@T" /persistent:no"
```

This fails because PowerShell interprets `7Ui4RT,@T` as an object, not a string (error = "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument 'System.Object[]'.").

What should I do?

Answer (score 7):

Why are you using [`Invoke-Expression`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113343) to evaluate your command? If you need to build up a set of arguments dynamically, you can place them in an array:

```powershell
$command = 'net'
$commandArgs = @('use','x:',$Path,'/USER:domain1\usr1','7Ui4RT,@T','/persistent:no')
& $command $commandArgs
```

If you know the command ahead of time, you can call it directly: `net $commandArgs`

Comment: Thanks for the `$commandArgs` suggestion. Using the array is much easier than trying to properly escape the string.

Answer (score 3):

Put single quotes around `7Ui4RT,@T`, i.e.

```
'7Ui4RT,@T'
```